# Python Selenium: Safari returns different text for span than Chrome and Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automated-tests

Binding: Python 3 Selenium
Browser: Safari, FireFox, Chrome

I am getting different text returned when making a call to get '.text' for a span that looks like the following: 
`<span class='my-upper' href='some/url'> my link</span>`
Where the class does:
`text-transform: uppercase;`

On Chrome and FireFox I get "My Link", but on Safari 11.0 I get " my link"
Note: lowercase and the leading space.  It looks like it is returning exact value from html and not what is displayed on the screen

Any one have any ideas on how to work around this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Chrome and Firefox inject the same [script](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/webdriver/atoms.cc?rcl=46b82cdc49e5baefb5be09520e989d4caeed0c31&l=8121) in the page to build the rendered text. It seems that Safari doesn't rely on this script.

One option would be to get the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) property:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg")).getAttribute("innerText")
```

or:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerText;", element);
```

But be aware that this property is not implemented by all the browsers and that the returned text may be different depending on the browser, especially on line breaks if the text is composed of multiple text nodes.

Comment: Thanks.  I will monkey patch the text method to either key off browser name or the elements _w3c setting (looks like Safari sets it to False, while others set True).  Now to work out why Safari does not like my `WebDriverWait(self._parent, 10).until(EC.visibility_of(self))` but other browsers work, oh well time to add another workaround.